# Расширение php_mysql

Tags: cron, apache, php

Приветствую! Была проблемка с запуском задания в corn. Так как я больше программист, чем системщик, то способом "втыка" выяснил, что проблема была, связанная с расширением **php_mysql.dll**. В php.ini я его закоментил, на работе сайта это не сказалось (*по крайней мере на первый взгляд*), но хотелось бы чисто для самообразования знать, что это за расширение, нужно ли оно для работы и, если да, то какую функцию оно выполняет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В смысле модуль? Стардартный php-шный модуль mysql это один из трёх модулей для работы с mysql (другие два mysqli и pdo-mysql). Если ваш код не использует этот модуль (а использовать его не рекомендуется, так-как он не безопасен и объявлен устаревшим) то проблем быть не должно.

Однако я сомневаюсь что проблемы с cron-ом могли-быть вызваны модулем php.В какой опирационной системе всё это происходит? Cron намекает на unix, в то-же время php_mysql**.dll** говорит в пользу windows.

Comment: @MrClon, покажу саму ошибку:> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to> load dynamic library> '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No> such file or directory in Unknown on> line 0И да, я не совсем правильно выразился. Cron запускался нормально, но т.к. задача в нем связана с работой с БД, то предупреждение не давало выполняться сценарию и было ощущение, что cron не отрабатывает.

Comment: P.S. Кстати, по поводу **.dll** у меня тоже были непонятки. Операционка Centos.

Comment: Кажется у вас какой-то странный php. Вы случайно не переносили часть его настроек из windows? Не знаю откуда ещё мог появиться php_mysql**.dll** в unix

Comment: @MrClon, настраивался сервер относительно давно и настраивал его не я, т.к. повторюсь, что я программист и с осью работаю на уровне дилетанта. Возможно что-то системщик напортачил... Проблем при работе с сайтами проблем не возникало и вылезла "бочина" только сейчас. Сам использую уже очень давно PDO, возможно, что именно поэтому не сталкивался с этой проблемой. В общем, как я понял, если этот модуль и имел место когда-то быть, то только для работы с устаревшим расширением **mysql_***, а т.к. оно мне не нужно, то закоментив в php.ini эту "непонятку", я сделал правильно. ))