# Единая шапка, меню и подвал на сайте без использования PHP и других серверных языков

Tags: javascript, html

Есть много страниц на сайте, отличаются только содержимым. Но если мне захочется изменить или логотип, или меню, или скажем подвал, то придётся их менять на всех страницах, что в общем то не сильно веселое занятие. PHP использовать не хочу в этом проекте, есть ли какие нибудь альтернативные способы это сделать?

Сделал на javascript, ибо первое что пришло на ум. Но потом засомневался: а нормально ли будет индексироваться сайт? Ведь если выключить скрипты, то пропадает короткая информация в футере и пропадают ссылки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [Server Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) ([рус](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))). Это более легковесная версия, которая поддерживается всеми современными веб-серверами. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
<!--#include file="footer.html" -->
```

JavaScript использовать не стоит: это и правда будет мешать индексации. Без серверной поддержки и нетриваильных телодвижений такие сайты нормально не индексируются.

Comment: ну, почему же? Анализировать URL, подгружать нужное  Ajax-ом + History API и вполне нормально будет индексироваться. Хотя, SSI тоже можно назвать выходом с таким раскладом, как у ТС.

Comment: @Deonis Как гугл-бот будет ваши аджаксы получать? Он видит голый HTML, на скрипты ему наплевать.

Comment: поисковые боты уже давно умеют работать с Ajax-ом. Это я утверждаю из личного опыта. Есть у меня проектик, который полностью работает на Ajax-е. В яндексе и гугле все ссылки, отправленные в карте, превосходно проиндексированы. При том, что и title и мета-данные страниц меняются динамически. Да, запрос обрабатывается на сервере, данные берутся из БД, но сути это не меняет.

Comment: @Deonis Покажите сайт что ли, который "полностью на аджаксе".

Comment: @Deonis Ваш сайт строит полноценный HTML. У вас не "сайт полностью на AJAX", а сайт с переходами между страницами, оптимизированными с помощью AJAX и History API. Если отключить JS (и скрыть идиотский лоадер или просто отключить стили), то будут видны полноценные страницы, построенные на сервере, вместе со всеми менюшкам и шапками. Что ж, вы меня успокоили. А то я боялся, что пропустил как поисковые боты начали полноценно выполнять JS.

Comment: Это называется fallback и строится он по определенным правилам (http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml).  Правда метку "#!" в URL, как предлагает тот же яндекс, я не делаю по причине того, что использую History.

Comment: @Deonis В карте сайта у вас указаны HTML страницы. Во внутрисайтовых ссылках у вас HTML страницы. Гугл и яндекс проиндексировали HTML страницы. Никаких фрагментов у вас в URL нет. Если вы возьмёте и выбросите абсолютно все скрипты (и даже карту сайта), то индексации это *абсолютно никак не помешает*. Это помешает только обычным пользователям, потому что вы зачем-то сделали нескрываемый лоадер. Я не понимаю, как можно пользоваться History API и не понимать, что делаешь...

Comment: Вас кто-то обидел, а то чувствуется какая-то раздраженность? Я понимаю больше, чем вы себе даже представить можете. А спорить с вами я не собираюсь, т.к. у меня есть занятия поинтересней.

Comment: @Deonis Меня раздражает, когда с умным видом говорят глупости. Не более того. / Смотрю ваши ответы, ничего умопомрачительного не вижу. Может, плохо ищу. Мне аж интересно стало, что я не могу себе представить.

Comment: @Deonis http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/348675 — так, ладно, я всё понял, вопросов больше не имею. :)

Comment: @Athari: какой сайт вы тут обсуждаете? интересно глянуть

Comment: @boris_U [site](http://toptema.tv) [sitemap](http://toptema.tv/sitemap.xml) [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:toptema.tv) [yandex](https://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=site:toptema.tv)

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть принцип - не вступать в холивары, даже если я в своей правоте уверен. Но для тех, кто будет читать данное обсуждение в будущем, я рекомендую прочитать отчет серии тестов того, как [Google индексирует динамицеский контент](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157), да и вообще, какие у гуглботов "отношения" с JS . Это вам поможет не обращать внимание на некоторых крикунов аля @Discord и не беспокоится, что использование Ajax-а может стать причиной плохой индексации сайта. Тем у кого сложности с английским, может почитать [переведенную статью](http://ain.ua/2015/05/13/579922), хотя оригинал - он и в Африке оригинал.